# How can I get the mouse coordinates related to a panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, click, mouse

I am trying to get the coordinates of a click with the mouse in C# related to a panel in my form, but I don't know how to do that. I'm a begginer and I don't have any experience with events. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

You must subscribe to event of Panel control - Click event.
You can write the code below within Form's contructor:

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel;

    public Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        panel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        panel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(82, 132);
        panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
        panel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.panel_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel);
    }

    private void panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point point = panel.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        MessageBox.Show(point.ToString());
    }
```

For more details about events go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Windows Forms then Cursor.Position

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = string.Format("X: {0} , Y: {1}", Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer the code sits in panel1_MouseMove insted form1_MouseMove