# How to know if mouse clicked point belongs to a rectangle or not?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

How to know the coordinates of a point in a rectangle that is drawn using graphics mechanism?
I want to recognize the rectangle on the basis of coordinate if the mouse click coordinate belong to the a rectangle i want to identify that rectangle.

EDITED I have drawn multiple rectangle, i want to recognize the rectangle on the basis of the mouse is clicked.

Comment: You need to store a list of all the rectangles you draw, including their location and size, and then on mouse click you need to do some simple point-to-box collision detection

Comment: @Erno de Weerd, i am not getting this.

Comment: @musefan would you please let me know in coding terms please.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: Sorry, thats too much work. Try it yourself first. You can get the mouse point relative to the control on click, [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377938/how-can-i-get-the-mouse-coordinates-related-to-a-panel). Then iterate through your list of rectangles and check if the point is within the bounds of the rectangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var point = new PointF(e.X, e.Y);
```

and then

```
var rectanglesContainingPoint = new List<RectF>();
foreach(var rectangle in rectangles)
{
    if(rectangle.Contains(point))
    {
        rectanglesContainingPoint.Add(rectangle);
    }
}
```

or

```
var rectanglesContainingPoint = 
     rectangles.Select(rectangle=>rectangle.Contains(point)).ToList();
```

You need to have stored all the rectangles in a list (rectangles).

Comment: LastOrDefault()  --> _rectangles.Select(rectangle=>rectangle.Contains(point)).LastOrDefault()_ Would be the topmost _Rectangle_ or _default(RectF)_ if the rectangles are drawn from back to front.

Comment: can i pass point like this   Text = String.Format("X: {0}; Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);

Comment: Make `point` like this: `var point = new PointF(e.X, e.Y);`